# Validating phone Number in Open cart using php

Tags: php, mysql, regex, field, opencart

**opencart 3**

```html
<div class="form-group ">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"> another telephone</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="another_telephone" value="{{another_telephone}}" class="form-control" placeholder="another telephone">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have added a **custom field** 'another-telephone' in vendor store form.
which is accepting alphabets, numbers and symbols.

**Question** : I want to validate my field for valid phone number .

[Image Attached : text field > another telephone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V51TZ.jpg)

Comment: It depends on your requirements for the phone number. Please find several regex patterns for phone numbers here: https://regexpattern.com/phone-number/

Comment: if( !preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $this->request->post['telephone']) ) {
      echo("<script>alert('phone number format must be correct')</script>");
      $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i do not understand correctly your question, but if you need to change your another-phone which is in letters to the numbers by Letters/numbers pattern `2(A,B,C) 3(D,E,F) 4(G,H,I) 5(J,K,L) 6(M,N,0) 7(P,Q,R,S) 8(T,U,V) 9(W,X,Y,Z)` you can try this:

```
$another_phone = 'holidays1';
$alias_array = array(
    '0' => ['0'],
    '1' => ['1'],
    '2' => ['A','B','C'],
    '3' => ['D','E','F'],
    '4' => ['G','H','I'],
    '5' => ['J','K','L'],
    '6' => ['M','N','O'],
    '7' => ['P','Q','R','S'],
    '8' => ['T','U','V'],
    '9' => ['W','X','Y','Z']);
    
$phone_in_letters = strtoupper($another_phone);
//creating an array
$phone_in_letters_array = str_split($phone_in_letters );

$phone_array = [];
foreach($phone_in_letters_array as $val) {
    foreach ($alias_array as $key => $letters) {
        if (in_array($val, $letters)) {
            $phone_array[] = $key;
        }
    }
}

print_r(implode($phone_array));
```

Comment: Thank u K.B. for your answer.  but a regex expression worked for me here.

if( !preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $this->request->post['telephone']) ) {
      echo("<script>alert('phone number format must be correct')</script>");
      $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
    }

Comment: It's ok. just the question little bit incorrect to understand what you exactly need. Because in your another-phone field was entered letters. See your attached image. Regex is good choice. I suggest to use this `$pattern = '/(?<!\S)\+?0*(?:' . $phone_country_code . '-)?\K(?:' . $phone_country_code . ')?[0-9]{9}(?!\S)/';` where you can check exactly your country code to validate the phone number.

Comment: ok i will use it.